# SOAP Service Client doesn't send Mime headers for Basic Auth

Tags: java, web-services, soap, basic-authentication

Some background: This is a Weblogic Web Services created Service client creates via Eclipse.  I believe this uses clientgen behind the scenes.

I'm trying to make a SOAP call that requires preemptive Basic Authentication.  The request is being sent but the Mimeheaders I'm setting are not going with it.  The recipient of the call has informed me that the request itself is coming through but any mimeheaders I set are not.

The service call is rather simple.

```
DescriptionService service = new DescriptionService(wsdlLocation, new QName("urn:descriptionService.service.company.com", "DescriptionService"));
service.setHandlerResolver(new HandlerResolver() {
  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  @Override
  public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(final PortInfo portInfo) {
    final List<Handler> handlerList = new ArrayList<Handler>();
    handlerList.add(new SOAPDescriptionServiceHeaderHandler());
    return handlerList;
  }
});

DescriptionServicePortType portType = service.getDescriptionServicePort();

DescriptionRequest request = new DescriptionRequest();
request.setId(id);
DescriptionResponse description = portType.describe(request);
```

The handler is where I set the Mimeheaders:

```
  @Override
  public boolean handleMessage(final SOAPMessageContext context) {
    final Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    final SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();

    if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
      try {
        MimeHeaders mimeheaders = message.getMimeHeaders();
        String encodedAuth = Base64.encode(new String("un:pw").getBytes());
        mimeheaders.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuth); 
        this.logMessage(message, outboundProperty.booleanValue(), false);
      } catch (final Exception e) {
        // Log Error
      }
    } else {
      this.logMessage(message, outboundProperty.booleanValue(), false);
    }
    return true;
  }
```

It does hit this handler and set the mimeheaders.  If I set a break point and look at the mime headers before it leaves the handleMessage method, I can see that they are set.

I'm able to call the request and get a response in SoapUI.  I set up preemptive basic auth and it works fine.  When I send the request through the Java Client, I get no response and actually get an error that says it's the incorrect content type.  I believe this error is referring to the fault response as I don't actually get the response (doesn't hit the handleMessage() method in the handler either) and I know the request is going through with text/xml which is what the error is asking for.

I'm unsure if it has something to do with the "preemptive" requirement?  Is there a way to set basic auth set up this way as preemptive?

Thoughts?
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Basic Auth is done at the HTTP layer, not the SOAP layer, so you need to configure the underlying HTTP library. (MIME headers have nothing to do with it)

For example for CXF, have a look at this question [HTTP basic authentication through CXF interceptor not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984319/http-basic-authentication-through-cxf-interceptor-not-working)